# cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); Gives me an error

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    while (true) {
        cin >> num;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Enter an integer: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
        else {
            cout << num;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this error on line 11:
namespace "std" has no member "numeric_limits"
type name is not allowed
no instance of overloaded function "max" matches the argument list

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Frws.png)

I am sorry for the vague question, I don't understand how the cin.ignore() function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```cpp
#include <limits>
```

to use [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), so add that to the top of your code.